# Program Error 1010 Prolog

Tags: visual-prolog

```
PREDICATES

nondeterm male(symbol)
nondeterm female(symbol)
nondeterm wife(symbol,symbol)

nondeterm mother(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm father(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm brother(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm sister(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm sonInLaw(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm brotherInLaw(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm uncle(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm sibling(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm grandson(symbol,symbol)
nondeterm grandfather(symbol,symbol)

Clauses

male(mark).
male(ahmed).
male(zeeshan).
male(summer).

female(sara).
female(sana).

wife(sara,mark).
wife(sana,ahmed).

mother(X,Y):-female(X),father(Z,Y),wife(X,Z),X<>Y.
mother(sara,sana).

father(X,Y):-male(X),mother(Z,Y),wife(Z,X),X<>Y.

brother(X,Y):-male(X),father(Z,X),father(Z,Y),X<>Y.

sister(X,Y):-female(X),father(Z,X),father(Z,Y),X<>Y.

sonInLaw(X,Y):-male(X),father(Y,Z),wife(Z,X) ; male(X),mother(Y,Z),wife(Z,X),X<>Y.

brotherInLaw(X,Y):-male(X),sister(Z,X),wife(Z,Y).

sibling(X,Y):-brother(X,Y);sister(X,Y),X<>Y.

uncle(X,Y):- sibling(X,Z),father(Z,Y),X<>Y.

grandfather(X,Y):- father(X,Z), father(Z,Y);father(X,Z), mother(Z,Y),X<>Y.

grandson(X,Y):- father(Z,X), father(Y,Z);father(Z,X), mother(Y,Z),X<>Y.

Goal

uncle(mark,sana).
```

My Prolog is giving me Error 1010.

Answer (score 0):

This should work
In WIP7 this works

```
class predicates
    male:(symbol) procedure (x).
    female:(symbol) procedure (x).
    wife:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    mother:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    father:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    brother:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    sister:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    sonInLaw:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    brotherInLaw:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    uncle:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    sibling:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    grandson:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).
    grandfather:(symbol,symbol)  procedure (x,y).

clauses
    male(mark).
    male(ahmed).
    male(zeeshan).
    male(summer).

    female(sara).
    female(sana).

    wife(sara,mark).
    wife(sana,ahmed).

    mother(X,Y):-female(X),father(Z,Y),wife(X,Z),X<>Y.
    mother(sara,sana).

    father(X,Y):-male(X),mother(Z,Y),wife(Z,X),X<>Y.

    brother(X,Y):-male(X),father(Z,X),father(Z,Y),X<>Y.

    sister(X,Y):-female(X),father(Z,X),father(Z,Y),X<>Y.

    sonInLaw(X,Y):-male(X),father(Y,Z),wife(Z,X);male(X),mother(Y,Z), wife(Z,X),X<>Y.

    brotherInLaw(X,Y):-male(X),sister(Z,X),wife(Z,Y).

    sibling(X,Y):-brother(X,Y);sister(X,Y),X<>Y.

    uncle(X,Y):- sibling(X,Z),father(Z,Y),X<>Y.

    grandfather(X,Y):-father(X,Z),father(Z,Y);father(X,Z),mother(Z,Y), X<>Y.

    grandson(X,Y):- father(Z,X), father(Y,Z);father(Z,X), mother(Y,Z),X<>Y.
clauses
    run():-
        console::init(),
    uncle(mark,sana),
    programControl::sleep(1000).
```

I think that with VIP 5.1 you can put

```
check_determ
```